# How to add 3d Breaklines to a raster in Arcgis desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d

I have prepared some breaklines from surveyed points. I want to modify a raster which has already been prepared for the area of interest based on these new breaklines.How can I do this in Arcgis desktop?

I've prepared this raster from Arcgis Ascii file. something like this :

```
ncols          301
nrows          801
xllcorner      383995.00000000
yllcorner      236995.00000000
cellsize       10.00000000
NODATA_value  -9999
-9999 11.9425 11.9487 12.0082 12.0337 11.941 11.9333 11.9294 11.9889 11.9194
11.8746 11.8893 11.8306 11.7449 11.7564 11.5078 11.2522 11.2105 11.2252 
11.2128  11.1542 11.2738 11.2406 11.3117 11.2684 11.3148 11.4144 12
```

Comment: How was your raster created? Which method/tool did you use? You will need to rebuild the raster to incorporate the breaklines.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the raster to TIN (Raster to TIN) then edit the TIN to add breaklines.  Once you've created the TIN, use the "Edit TIN" tool to input Features into the existing TIN - among other options, you can add the 3D lines as hard lines. You can also manually edit and clean up the TIN with the TIN Editing toolbar after the fact if necessary and optionally export the TIN back to raster with the TIN to Raster conversion tool.  All of this requires the 3D Analyst extension.

As @Nxau suggested, and if you do not have the 3D Analyst Extension, you may need to build your raster ground up but with breaklines as barriers/cliff line/stream line/contour line/ etc.  Have a look at the Spline interpolation with Barriers or the Topo to Raster tools.

You can also create terrain datasets and add breaklines but like TINS this is a vector surface but unlike TIN it's designed to render data based on map scale for more efficient display. Terrain datasets can handle very large datasets such as LiDAR.